# Understanding how transactions work

Tags: hibernate, spring-transactions

I am working with Spring and using hibernate and JPA. When I provide a Transactional Context for my method I want to know how it works. For example I had some Entity Class Person. I created a Person `bob` and persisted the entity. If i call `getPersonByName("bob")` will it return bob before the transaction is closed?

Comment: If you mean to say that the persistence (saving) and retrieval (getPersonByName) are part of same method then it will not return as the object is persisted when the method execution is completed and thread exists the method.

If the persistence and retrieval are separated out in 2 methods with different transaction boundaries then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: it depends how your **read** operation is implemented.

You can switch on logging and setup a test-harness to see for yourself. You can follow [these instructions to enable SQL queries and parameters printing](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-logging-guide/).

2 caveats:

1. I'm assuming we are within transactional boundaries when we perform write and then read (in Spring `@Transactional` method(s) with default **Propagation** level)
2. Not sure how your getPersonByName("bob") works underneath (Spring-Data? or JPQL/HQL? or Criteria? or find() etc).

In Hibernate **1st Level Cache** is activated by default. It is linked to a Hibernate **Session** and all entities fetched by it are stored within the Session. *As a result a subsequent read right after a write should not round-trip to the DB within the same Session*.

Now Hibernate's **1st Level Cache** is not used by default unless you are using:

- **EntityManager#find()** for the subsequent **read** operation
- Subsequently accessing relationships via getter methods from the above **EntityManager#find()** fetched entities
- It's not used on any kind of Queries